# bash - reading user variable into bash script grep

Tags: bash, regular-expression, variable

I've tried every possible combination to get this bash script working. It's part of a larger script, and it basically prompts for a username (to check if it exists) and returns the appropriate response:

```
#! /bin/bash
# Script to see if User exists

clear
echo -n "Enter user to check: "
read $uzer

grep -c '^${uzer}:' /etc/passwd

if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
  echo "User does exist :)"
else
  echo "No such user"
fi
```

In terminal the following works fine:

```
grep -c '^devuser1:' /etc/passwd
RETURNS: 1
grep -c '^devuser1234:' /etc/passwd
RETURNS: 0
```

I've tried many combinations of passing the read variable into `'^${uzer}:'` with no joy. Any ideas what else I can try?

Comment: `read $uzer` should be `read uzer`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`-c` means that you want to know the number of times this user is in `/etc/passwd`, while `$?` is the exit code. Those are differents, since the number of times is printed on stdout. Use `$()` for getting stdout into a variable

Second problem: all your variables, like `$uzer` will not be substituted with their values when in single quotes. Use double quotes.

```
number=$(grep -c "^${uzer}:" /etc/passwd)
if [ $number -gt 0 ]; then
  echo "User does exist :)"
else
  echo "No such user"
fi
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! However, I get the following error:
`Enter user to check: devuser1
./userexist.sh: line 8: =0: command not found
./userexist.sh: line 10: [: -eq: unary operator expected
No such user`

Comment: sorry, can't do newlines in comments!

Comment: right. I already corrected my answer. Please use `number` instead of `$number` in the assignment.

Comment: Sweet! I didn't even notice the `$` at the beginning. No errors now, but it returns "No such user" even for a user that I know exists. I feel it has something to do with the way `$uzer` is used in the regex

Comment: there is an error in the `read` command: it must be `read uzer` rather than `read $uzer`.

Comment: You're a STAR!! Thank you! This is my first dive into bash scripting so still getting used to the syntax :)

Comment: Bourne shell and bash distinguish between a variable and its current value. If you want the current value of variable `A`, it's `$A`; if you want the container rather than what's inside (i.e., in assignments `A=...` and `read A`) the `$` is missing.

Comment: That would still think that the `r.ot` and `root:0` users exist though. Using `grep` here is wrong. It must be `IFS= read -r uzer`, not `read uzer` let alone `read $uzer`

Answer (score 2):

You need `grep -q`. If you don't distinguish between more exit codes than "0" and "other" there is no need to seperate grep and if:

```
if grep -q "^${uzer}:" /etc/passwd; then
  echo "User does exist :)"
else
  echo "No such user"
fi
```

Comment: The single quotes around `^${uzer}:` must be replaced by double quotes, otherwise the variable `${uzer}` is not expanded.

Comment: @Uwe How embarrassing. I just copied the code and was looking at the other problem only...

Comment: Hi Hauke. Thanks anyway for your response. The answer from eppesuig above worked like a charm. I did something similar to this before, and the error I got was "...too many arguments..."